# powershell multiple sql query in while loop

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have the following code in a PowerShell script:

```
$conn = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection
$conn.DatabaseName = "AdventureWorks2012"
$reader = $conn.ExecuteReader("SELECT Name, CostRate FROM Production.Location")
while ($reader.Read())
{
  $name = $reader.GetValue(0);
  $cRate = $reader.GetValue(1);
  Write-Host $name,"(",$cRate,")"
}
$reader.Close()
```

How can you execute another select query inside the while loop?

Comment: Can you explain WHY you want to do that? Consider that you've got an open active connection to your database at this point. Why can't you do it AFTER you've closed your datareader?

Comment: I know that I can do that but I would like to know how to implement a second sql select query inside the loop. Is it possible??

Comment: You need to explain what result you're looking for, not the method you've already settled on for reaching it. It may be the case that you're approaching it completely wrong, and there's a *far* better method that matches accepted practices & patterns. Right now, we're looking at an XY problem. For example, if the code you have here was all that you needed to accomplish, I can think of at least 2 ways to do it better.

Answer (score -1):

You should be opening you connection with MARS enabled in order to open another datareader in the same connection. Look at this article, describing how to do it in C#, you can easily adapt it for ps :
http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Using-MARS-technique-in-CNET-20-720.php

Comment: The example given there is pretty poor. The same result could (and should) be achieved via a simple `JOIN`, and the lack of Prepared Statements (and use of string concatenation to build the query) is a big red flag for me, especially in a web app.

Comment: Yep, I was answering the question as it was asked, and I think you are right to answer it more thorougly than I did. There are better ways to do it.